# Load fragment data only on time

Tags: android, android-viewpager

```
class GoogleMusicAdapter extends TestFragmentAdapter implements TitleProvider {
    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0)
            return MyClass.newInstance();
        else if(position == 1)
            return MyClass.newInstance();
        else
            return MyClass.newInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return SampleTabsStyled.CONTENT.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(int position) {
        return SampleTabsStyled.CONTENT[position % SampleTabsStyled.CONTENT.length];
    }

}
```

I have a AsyncTask in my MyClass class.I use this GoogleMusicAdapter class in my viewpager.Whenever i change page to another it runs asynctask one more time but i don't want it.It must be run on start and mustn't called one more time.How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a singleton?

```
private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private MyAsyncTask mInstance;

    public static boolean executeIfNotCreated() {
        if(mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MyAsyncTask();
            mInstance.execute();
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okey but how can i run asynctask with that?Like "new MyAsyncTask().executeIfNotCreated();" ?

Comment: Good point... `executeIfNotCreated()` should be `static`. Fixed my example. So you'd call `MyAsyncTask.executeIfNotCreated()`.

Comment: It doesn't work.Because it wants that every variable have to be static.